# Virtual Host Overriding Hello World On Another Server

Tags: linux, webserver, desktop-computer, virtual-host, httpd

For some reason, the content of `0rcan0mic.com` on my main server is overriding `constantcounselling.com` on another server. I want to get hello world on `constantcounselling.com` instead of the contents of `0rcan0mic.com'` loading on `constantcounselling.com`. Apache is running.

Also, for domains on the same server as `0rcan0mic.com` (my main server), hello world shows up for them, like `mybestfriendsarecats.com` and `orcaaccounting.com`.

*Results of `httpd -S`*

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using requin.themartialartsofmoney.com. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  requin.themartialartsofmoney.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:56)
*:80                   constantcounselling.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/constantcounselling.com:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/etc/httpd/logs/error_log"
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-client: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex authn-socache: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/run/httpd/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-opaque: using_defaults
PidFile: "/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
Define: _RH_HAS_HTTPPROTOCOLOPTIONS
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="apache" id=48
Group: name="apache" id=48
```

*Virtual Hosts*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   
    ServerName constantcounselling.com
    ServerAlias www.constantcounselling.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/constantcounselling.com/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/constantcounselling.com-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/constantcounselling.com-access.log combined


    <Directory "/var/www/constantcounselling.com/public_html">
      AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =constantcounselling.com [OR]
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.constantcounselling.com
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   
    ServerName 0rcan0mic.com
    ServerAlias www.0rcan0mic.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/0rcan0mic.com/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/0rcan0mic.com-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/0rcan0mic.com-access.log combined


    <Directory "/var/www/0rcan0mic.com/public_html">
      AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.0rcan0mic.com [OR]
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =0rcan0mic.com
 RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
 </VirtualHost>
```

Help greatly appreciated, I've been stuck on this for weeks.

Comment: Are these virtual servers (i.e. cloud based)?

Comment: 0rcan0mic.com is on my bare metal machine im typing from now. constantcounselling.com is on a customer's server.